# HttpUrlConnection cutting inputstream returned

Tags: android, inputstream, httpurlconnection

I am trying to get  an inputStrem from a web server using this code

```
private InputStream downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException {
 URL url = new URL(urlString);
 HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
 conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
 conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
 conn.setDoInput(true);
 InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
 return stream;
}
```

When I try to use this inputstream to get a String I am missing the beggining and the end, so it seems it is cutting something.
However using DefaultHttpClient , HttpGet and HttpResponse the result is ok.

```
    private String downloadPHP(String urlString){


            String st = null;// aqui el XML descargado

            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);         

            try {
                HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();
                st = StringUtils.inputStreamToString(content);


            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                //Log.i(Constants.DEBUG_TAG, e.getMessage());

            }

            return st;
    }
```

Since Google is recomending the use of HttpUrlConnection, any idea to solve this issue?

This is the method to get the string from the inoutstream

```
public static String inputStreamToString(final InputStream stream) throws IOException {
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    br.close();
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: I quickly tested your code and it seems to work fine. I put it all in the same function, though. What do you mean by "missing the beginning and the end"?

Comment: Hi, I am making a request to a web server to get some information from a database. It should return a string with a xml format like

Comment: Hi, I am making a request to a web server to get some information from a database. It should return a string in xml fomrat including all the tags etc. Using DefaultHttpClient everything is ok but using HttpUrlConnection the information returned is worng, I am missing part of the first tag (the first one in the document) and the information is cut in some poinnt in the middle

Comment: side node: should it really be `HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);` and not `urlString`? Maybe you are calling something else in the downloadPHP method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have reviewed the code again and also the server side and finally it is a problem with the data send by the server. The server is not sending the data in the proper format. We have changed the php code and now using HttpUrlCOnnection as it described in the original question everything is working.
In the server side the information was not being getting the xml format, we have solved it using PHP DOM

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below to read from input stream.

```
byte[] buf;    
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(8192);
int read = inputStream.read();

while (read != -1) {
    baos.write((byte) read);
    read = inputStream.read();
}

baos.flush();
buf = baos.toByteArray();
```